# Why might a company buy back their shares at a price above market value?

Tags: stocks, investing

Some companies buy back their shares at a higher price than what is currently listed in the market. What is the benefit to the company, vs just buying at the current value?

Comment: "higher price" — Higher than what? Could you give some examples?

Comment: Higher than market price of company's own share

Answer (score 3):

> Some companies buy back their shares at a higher price. What is the
> benefit to the company.

Let's assume that you aren't talking about a situation where Company B or rich person C is trying to take over company A.

This is just company A buying back shares of company A.

In this case they believe that in x months or years they will be able to sell those shares for higher price compared to the price today.

They also do this as a way to spend some of their cash. They believe that the best use of their cash is to buy their shares. They aren't interested in expanding their production facilities, or pouring  more money into research and development, or buying another company. Of course if they change their mind in a couple of years, they can always sell those shares again.

They can also view the repurchasing of the shares as a dividend for their current shareholders. Some will sell because they can lock in their profits. In addition The smaller number of shares in circulation makes them more valuable.

Sometimes they also do this to project confidence that the company is stronger then the market currently believes. If potential shareholders believe this also, the price will rise.

Comment: It is worth pointing out as well that it would still be to the company's benefit to buy back their shares at as low a price as possible - but a large order would likely be higher than what the price is currently listed at, because only a certain number of people would be willing to sell at that price. So, the price is raised to attract enough sellers to spend the desired amount of otherwise 'excess' cash.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mhoran_psprep's excellent answer, most publicly traded companies a) compensate executives heavily in shares and b) tie said compensation to share performance.

For example: https://www.reuters.com/technology/elon-musk-scores-hat-trick-tesla-compensation-goals-worth-23-billion-2022-04-20/

> Musk, who is also a major shareholder and CEO of rocket maker SpaceX, receives no salary at Tesla. His pay package requires Tesla's market capitalization and financial growth to hit a series of escalating targets.
>
> Each tranche gives Musk the option to buy 8.4 million Tesla shares at $70.01 each, a discount of about 90% from Wednesday's closing price of $977.20. At the stock's current price, the three options tranches that will vest as a result of Tesla's March-quarter performance could generate a profit of about $23 billion, or almost $7.7 billion per tranche.

This means goosing the share price both gets you compensated, and raises the value of that compensation. Being able to spend company money to increase the value of your own money is a handy trick, and the other shareholders tend not to complain about it because they're benefiting from the same rise.

Comment: The flaw in reasoning here is that buying shares back at a higher price than the current listed value is not guaranteed to increase share price - consider an extreme example where the company runs out of liquid cash, and suddenly needs to drop potential projects that it needs to sustain growth. If a company's corporate payout structure is poorly designed, yes manipulation is still possible but it is not necessarily the case that other shareholders would support such a move it it led to long-term financial difficulties for the company.

Comment: To the extent this is truly best for shareholders in the long term, it is only true per the notions in @mhoran's answer - that the company may believe it is currently undervalued by the market, and simultaneously has nowhere else to park excess cash, so determines this is the best outcome.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon It needn't be good for all shareholders in the long-term for these motivations to play a role. Wall Street is a bit notorious for short-sighted thinking in these matters. In cases whether other shareholders might not support things, that's easily fixed; Musk's Tesla shares have weighted voting power that gives him full control anyways. Nice setup!

Comment: It is illegal for minority shareholders to have value unfairly stripped to the benefit of individual actors. This doesn't mean it can't happen - again, manipulation can occur, and suing a Board for such action requires a high bar to be successful. The stated reason for a company doing this would be per the other answer, and to the extent that voting bloc does so for their own personal benefit [again - not guaranteed that this is good for Musk either except for very specific regulations on his comp], it would be considered manipulation.

Comment: Consider - Musk has stock options, Tesla buys back shares at an inflated price [an offer which would proportionately be available to current shareholders to take advantage of], Tesla runs into liquidity issues, and let's assume refinances through an additional share offering - at a new lower, market-approved price. In such a case, this type of manipulative action could negatively impact Musk for the value of his remaining shares in the company. **You couldn't legally just have a public company buy back a specific individual's shares at an inflated price**.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon You don't buy back a specific individual's. You buy back off the open market. Because you're among the biggest shareholders, you benefit from the increase. There's plenty of evidence this happens; https://www.reuters.com/investigates/special-report/usa-buybacks-pay/

Comment: That article specifically talks about instances of executive compensation being tied to arbitrary measures like EPS, where the 'Per Share' part of the equation isn't modified by shares bought back by the company. Barring that or a similar mechanism [again, as I've said, yes manipulation can occur], buybacks more or less help or hurt all shareholders in equal measure.